# Convert ColdFusion Scheduled Job to .net

Tags: .net

Below is a description of a system that works very well for running scheduled jobs in ColdFusion.  If you were to build something in .net that was at least as good if not better, how would you do it?  Note that I'm looking for concepts, ideas, and structures - not code.

We currently have a "plug and play" concept for scheduled jobs in ColdFusion.  Instead of several dozen individual scheduled jobs, there are a handful of scheduled job containers.  It is the containers that are actually scheduled in ColdFusion.  Each container is scheduled to run at a different time of day.  Developers plug their individual job into the most  appropriate container based on what time they want their job to run.
The container files have names like ScheduledJobs_0600.cfm.    They are located in a directory not available to web browsers.  There is a separate log file associated with each.

Once an individual job is ready to be scheduled, the developer plugs it into the container file like this:

The translation is that on the 5th day of each month, ColdFusion file /DWsystem/jobs/AdultPsych.cfm will run.

cf_RunJob is a ColdFusion custom tag.  It
•   trys to run the job.
•   if successful, a line is written to a log file indicating when the job started and how many milliseconds it took to run.
•   if unsuccessful, the catch block writes the error message to the log file

The try/catch method prevents one coding error from preventing subsequent individual jobs from running.

There are two other scheduled jobs that see how the other ones went.  Specifically, they read the most recent entries in the log files and look for errors.  If any are found, all the daily events from that particular file are emailed to certain address groups.
There are also two web pages available to follow up when things don't go well.  One lists all the "container" jobs and allows users to run any or all of them.  The container jobs are hard coded, but, since they are in the same directory, they could be obtained programmatically.

The second page is a little more elaborate.  It reads all the container files and all the log files.  The user is then presented with a list of all individual jobs, each one accompanied by a checkbox.  Any job that failed on its previous attempt has the checkbox pre-checked.  The execution time is also shown for each job.  When the form is submitted, each selected job is run with the cf_RunJob tag.

How would you do it in .net?

Comment: Can you create a Windows Service?

Comment: I'm very new to .net.  I think I can figure out how to create a Windows Service.  However, is it possible for one service to call another?